# react-intl maintain number of digits in original number

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am using `react-intl` for formatting number based on locale.

For `cs` locale, 
`this.props.intl.formatNumber(-0.0001)` is returning `-0`. I want library to return `-0,0001`. So, i don't want to round number.

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify `minimumFractionDigits`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat